# Getting error '< Unexpected' in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, json, laravel-5

Here is my `Routes.php`

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1', 'middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
    Route::post('login', array('UsersController@user_login'));
});
```

And Here is my `UsersController.php`

```
 public function user_login()
    {

        $email_id = Input::get('email_id');
        $name = Input::get('name');
        $api_token = str_random(50);

                DB::table('users')-> insertGetId(array(
                    'email_id' => $email_id,
                    'name' => $name,
                    'api_token' => $api_token
                ));

            $API = DB::table('users')->select('api_token')->
            where('email_id' , '=' , $email_id)->get();

            return response()->json(['api_token'=> $API]);

}
```

I am getting

> '< Unexpected Error'

when I test my code in Postman.
Where am I lacking in my code ?

Any help would be grateful.
Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a comma:

```
DB::table('users')-> insertGetId(array(
    'email_id' => $email_id,// This comma was missing
    'name' => $name,
    'api_token' => $api_token
 ));
```

Comment: @BhavinShah Is there anything getting logged in `storage/logs`?

Comment: there is nothing in `storage/logs`. I have checked it